# Why do decoders have a reverse current when the output voltage is high?

Tags: decoder

So I am designing a pcb using a STM32 microcontroller and I wanted to expand the output pins in order to add a sensor. So I thought of using a 2-to-4 decoder in order to 'add' 2 pins. However, when searching for a decoder like this, I found out that, in their datasheets, a reverse current was applied when the high level output voltage was active.

Here is a table of the SN54AHC139 decoder from Texas Instruments with its recommended oparation conditions:

[image]

Why is this? I understand that it is an active-low decoder but I don't get why the current is reversed.

Answer (score 4):

The current flowing into a pin that sinks current has a positive sign and current flowing out from a pin that sources current has a negative sign. The direction of current really is different and the sign reflects that.